# Sound from picaxe

Tags: sound, picaxe

i have PICAXE-28 Project Board and PICAXE-28X1 IC. What is the easiest way to play music on those? I don't want to buy something that is already made, i want to make it myself, but I dunno how :D
What about this
http://sites.google.com/site/roidayan/simple-mp3-player-hacking
Or you can show me a better guide?

Answer (score 3):

You can start by synthesizing sounds via PWM. This course has several nice lectures on sound effect synthesis via PWM: http://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECD7F7ED1F3505D8D5

The base of the course is an AVR microcontroller, but the topics are about general microcontroller programming. Sound synthesis topic starts at lecture #12.

Answer (score 0):

From the PICAXE web site:

What notes are generated by the sound command?

The sound command generates different 'beep' sounds for the values 1-127.

The tune and play commands are specifically designed to play tunes and musical notes.

Comment: By sound i mean music, not just beep sounds :D

Comment: It says that you can play tunes with the tune and play commands!